# Set a selected option of a dropdown using angular bootstrap select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-select, angular-bootstrap

Im trying to set an option with angular bootstrap select(in my example I use a simple button), I update the ng-model and I can see the select changes, and quickly return to the default value.

This is a snippet of code:

```
function SelectCtrl($scope, $timeout) {

   $scope.options = [
        {value: 'option1', text: 'option 1'},
        {value: 'option2', text: 'option 2'},
        {value: 'option3', text: 'option 3'}
    ];


    $scope.updateOption = function() {


       $scope.theOption = $scope.options[0];

       $timeout(function() {  
         $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
       }); 
    }

}
```

This is the **[EXAMPLE](http://plnkr.co/edit/KHhHqUpJ3k2rcaUlQRVn?p=preview)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bug in the directive defined in angular-bootstrap-select.js, remove this part and try:

```
  ngModel.$render = function () {
    $timeout(function () {
      element.selectpicker('val', element.val() || '');
    });
  };
```

Comment: Could you be more precise? I cannot seem to use $timeout in there as the bootstrap-select doesn't get injected correctly if I do.

Answer (score -1):

Commenting out the line "$scope.theOption = $scope.options[0];" should work.

This should work:

```
angular.module('selectDemoApp', ['angular-bootstrap-select', 'angular-bootstrap-select.extra']);

function SelectCtrl($scope, $timeout) {

  $scope.options = [
            {value: 'option1', text: 'option 1'},
            {value: 'option2', text: 'option 2'},
            {value: 'option3', text: 'option 3'}
        ];


 $scope.updateOption = function() {


     //$scope.theOption = $scope.options[0];

     $timeout(function() {  
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
     });

 }

}
```